# Pgfplots - large plot - TeX capacity exceeded

Tags: pgfplots, pdftex, plot, shell-escape, memory

I have a following code, which is supposed to generate some output and one large plot from the file `data5.csv`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{ Solve_RegCG_singular_dom_itersolver.cpp:110 }
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\pagebreak

\section{Lumped Preconditioner and SPDS (sparse-sparse)}

\textbf{CG Solver Overall Evaluation}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Default: 4207.879395 J (24th, 2500000Hz)
    \item Optimal: 4207.879395 J (24th, 2500000Hz)
    \item Static savings: 0.0 J (0.00 \%)
\end{itemize}

\begin{adjustbox}{center, set height=\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={ 24_1200000_PREC1_SCHUR0.csv },
xlabel={ Number of samples },
ylabel={ Power [W] },
legend pos=outer north east,
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
no markers,
width=24cm,
height=11cm,
cycle list name = color list
]
\addplot table [ x=ind, y=val, col sep=comma] {data5.csv};
\legend{ 0 }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

[Here is the link](https://uloz.to/!9tm5UFwpE/data5-csv) with the file `data5.csv`.

---

**The problem** is, that when I try to compile my code, I'm getting following error:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=7000000].
<argument> ...875e3],1Y9.1125e1],}{;1Y3.876e3\ETC.
l.46 ... x=ind, y=val, col sep=comma] {data5.csv};
```

As we can see, I've already tried to resize the memory according to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-to-expand-texs-main-memory-size-pgfplots-memory-overload), but, unfortunately, it isn't enough.

---

**My other attempt** was the use of externalization according to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7953/how-to-expand-texs-main-memory-size-pgfplots-memory-overload). I've changed my code like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, landscape]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize

\makeatletter
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{ Solve_RegCG_singular_dom_itersolver.cpp:110 }
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\pagebreak

\section{Lumped Preconditioner and SPDS (sparse-sparse)}

\textbf{CG Solver Overall Evaluation}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Default: 4207.879395 J (24th, 2500000Hz)
    \item Optimal: 4207.879395 J (24th, 2500000Hz)
    \item Static savings: 0.0 J (0.00 \%)
\end{itemize}

\begin{adjustbox}{center, set height=\textheight}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title={ 24_1200000_PREC1_SCHUR0.csv },
xlabel={ Number of samples },
ylabel={ Power [W] },
legend pos=outer north east,
xmajorgrids=true,
ymajorgrids=true,
grid style=dashed,
no markers,
width=24cm,
height=11cm,
cycle list name = color list
]
\addplot table [ x=ind, y=val, col sep=comma] {data5.csv};
\legend{ 0 }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}


\end{document}
```

And I'm compiling it with the command `pdflatex -shell-escape`. The problem is, I'm getting following error now:

```
! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -shell-escape -halt-on-e
rror -interaction=batchmode -jobname "results-figure0" "\def\tikzexternalrealjo
b{results}\input{results}"' did NOT result in a usable output file 'results-fig
ure0' (expected one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enab
led system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'. Sometimes it 
is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or maybe the command simply fa
iled? Error messages can be found in 'results-figure0.log'.
```

---

So, do you have any idea, what am I doing wrong? Or is it simply impossible to print a plot of this size just with `pdflatex`?

Comment: Try running it through `lualatex.`

Comment: Well 46000 rows are quite a lot. Consider to reduce the data file see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/305669/2388

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/286454/tex-capacity-exceeded-using-pgfplots-with-without-externalization/286610#286610), in other answers in SE, and as @JPi pointed out in a comment, LuaLaTeX can be the solution to you problem.
In particular you have to run `lualatex` instead of `pdflatex`, with the same option (`-shell-escape` or `-enable-write18`). After the image has been externalized, you can fall back on `pdflatex`, as long as you don't introduce a new picture or change an existing one, in which case you have to run `lualatex` once more.