# Line plot from csv file in tikz format

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following loss plot data in a csv file. With columns (a) Epochs, (b) Test_loss , (c) Train_loss and 10,000 row entries of this data (As 10,000 epochs in total).  I want to plot this on a tikz format how to do so?

**I have the format as ;**

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[
xmin=0, xmax=1e2,
ymin=1e-7, ymax=1e1,
xlabel={Number of Epochs}, 
ylabel={Normalized MSE: $\log_{10} (e)$ },
label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
tick label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
scatter/classes={a={mark=square*, blue}, b={mark=triangle*, red}, c={mark=o, black}},
]
\addplot[scatter, only marks,
scatter src=explicit symbolic]
table[meta=label] {
x     y      label
};
\end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image].

**My csv file looks like this.**

Epochs,Test_loss,Train_loss

0,0.203095777,0.234712227

1,0.202614659,0.234308232

2,0.202137079,0.233968432

**Link to the csv file:** I have copied the first 20 rows of the 2000 row dataset in this file and named it as 3N5H_test.csv .

[csv file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zXuXRUeIkwvj-f3LEhOoPNyszUHsm0ON/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Could you maybe add the first three or so lines of your CSV file? You may use modified values, but it would be good to know about the concrete format of the file.

Comment: I am not sure to understand the question. Could https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248723/plot-large-data help?

Comment: In the liked CSV file there is a BOM (byte order mark) at the beginning of the file (it is an invisible character that sits before the first visible character of the file). It is best to delete this BOM. To do this, place the cursor behind the first character of the file, press the left-arrow key only once, press delete at least twice, save the file.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Hey, that actually works for the test file. But having memory issue for the 2000 row file. `TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].`

Comment: Maybe, as for the memory problem, some of the ideas linked here can help you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/319004/47927

Comment: Cool thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am unsure how your CSV file looks like, but guessing from what you describe, an easy approach could be as follows: I understand that you got a CSV file with a content similar to this:

```
Epoch, Test_loss, Train_loss, Test_metric
1,     0.02,      0.03,       0.025
1000,  0.01,      0.005,      0.015
...
```

In this case, you can simply parse this by adding an `\addplot` macro for each of the columns that you want to plot, let `x` be the `Epoch` column and `y` the column with the relevant values:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

% your CSV file:
\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
Epoch, Test_loss, Train_loss, Test_metric
1,     0.02,      0.03,       0.025
1000,  0.01,      0.005,      0.015
\end{filecontents}
% =====

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
    xmin=0, xmax=1e4,
    ymin=1e-4, ymax=1e-1,
    scaled x ticks=false,
    xlabel={Number of Epochs}, 
    ylabel={Normalized MSE: $\log_{10} (e)$},
    label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
    tick label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
]
\addplot[scatter, no marks, draw=blue] 
    table [x=Epoch, y=Test_loss, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\addplot[scatter, no marks, draw=red] 
    table [x=Epoch, y=Train_loss, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\addplot[scatter, no marks, draw=orange] 
    table [x=Epoch, y=Test_metric, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you don't need to include the CSV data in your TeX file. Just place the CSV file in the same directory where your TeX file is stored, and write, e.g., `\addplot[scatter, no marks, draw=blue] table [...] {<file name>};`. You can just ignore the stuff between `\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}` and `\end{filecontents}` (including these two lines) in this case, since this is just to make the above example compilable.

---

Sorry, I cannot really reproduce the problems you have. I adjusted the above example with the data you provided:

The file `3N5H.csv` (note that there should probably be no empty lines in the CSV file, because these would be interpreted as (empty) data points):

```
Epochs,Test_loss,Train_loss
0,0.203095777,0.234712227
1,0.202614659,0.234308232
2,0.202137079,0.233968432
```

The TeX file:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
    % xmin=0, xmax=1e4,      % The output would not be visible otherwise
    % ymin=1e-4, ymax=1e-1,  % The output would not be visible otherwise
    scaled x ticks=false,
    enlargelimits,
    xlabel={Number of Epochs}, 
    ylabel={Normalized MSE: $\log_{10} (e)$},
    label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
    tick label style={font=\bfseries\boldmath},
]
\addplot[scatter, no marks, draw=blue] table [x=Epochs, y=Test_loss, col sep=comma] {3N5H.csv};
\addplot[scatter, no marks, draw=red] table [x=Epochs, y=Train_loss, col sep=comma] {3N5H.csv};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Oh, I actually have 2000 data points in my csv file. Do I need to type all that? Can I not directly import it?

Comment: Yes you can. Just place the CSV inside the same directory and replace `data.csv` (for each `\addplot`) with the name of this file. You don't need to include the CSV data in your TeX file. The above is just to make a minimal working example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, I have updated my question with how my csv looks like.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't able to get the result . I tried `table [x={Epoch}, y={Test_loss}, col sep=space] {3N5H.csv};` 3N5H.csv is the name of the csv file, stored in the same folder as the tex file.

Comment: @Formal_this From how the CSV looks like as you showed in your answer, it should be `table [x={epochs}, y={Test loss}, col sep=comma] {3N5H.csv}`. You need to use the  exact column names from the CSV, which are typically the values in the first row of the CSV. Also, you should check what the column separator of your CSV really is. Open the CSV with a text editor and double check. It is most likely `comma` or `tab`.

Comment: Yeah, i checked all that. This error is remaining ;

Comment: <to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.17 ...s, y=Test_loss, col sep=comma] {3N5H.csv};
                                                  ^^M
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.

! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   E
l.17 ...s, y=Test_loss, col sep=comma] {3N5H.csv};
                                                  ^^M
A number should have been here; I inserted '0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.

Comment: I added how the csv looks like

Comment: hey may you kindly help me on this. thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey Jasper, thanks a lot for all your help! In order to conclude the problem, I have added a csv file in my question, which I copied from my original file. May you kindly help me try to plot this and see if this works or not? Again thanks a lot for your help. I tried to plot this with your code and the plot appears but no point is visible. While the same code was throwing error for the 2000 row dataset.

Comment: @Formal_this After having deleted the BOM in the CSV you linked above (see my comment to your question about this), I was able to plot the data. Do you want to add marks for the single data points on the plot?

Comment: No, I wish to have a continuous plot only.

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually that did work all well. But for 2000 rows, it shows TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=5000000].