# How to plot measured signals? i.e. large number of points

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable

So far I used TikZ/PFGplots to plot small potions of (simulated) signals, drawing schemes, etc. but when it comes to actually measured signals (e.g. at 10 kHz), you easily end up with millions of points. Very quick you run into the **TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [main memory size=54000000]**-error. While the obvious workaround is either to exceed the memory (not really recommended) or use `externalize` (only useful if you render multiple images), both are not a practical solution for raw data.

While it works fairly well with 100,000 (1e5) rows (each containing x and y value) but breaks if you go much larger. However, assuming 10kHz, this is translates to a signal of 10s maximum...

**Q: Is there an efficient way to plot large signals in TeX?**

MWE: (assuming the data in a file `data.csv` with two columns `x` and `y`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot table [mark=none,x=x, y=y, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

For the file `data.csv`. Take this [file here](https://gigamove.rz.rwth-aachen.de/d/id/bJSXQfn6eJYfQC), or use the snippet of MATLAB code to reproduce the file yourself:

```
x = (1:1e6).';
y = awgn( ((x-1/3*length(x))/length(x)*10).^2,20,'measured');
writetable(table(x,y),'data.csv');
```

I was wondering if there is a script to downsample the data but keeping the most significant points automatically. In particular I want to `spy` on the data, it needs the original resolution in this area...

Comment: My suggestion: R manage well plots with thousands of points, that with the help of  `kintr`  could be really tikz plots, like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305665/scatterplot-exceeds-memory-capacity),  [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468004/11604) or [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/467161/11604)

Comment: This could also shed some idea: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248723/plot-large-data

Comment: `pgfplots` has a whole subsection on this: **6.1 Memory Limits of TEX**, but it is also true that there are limitations and LaTeX is not necessarily made to plot so large numbers of samples.

Comment: waoh people, thx for the great ideas! I'll to a bit of reading on those. In particular I like the combination with R as it maintains the look of the other figures generated with `pgfplots` =)

Comment: @Fran Assume I can mange to learn a bit of R to use the `kintr` library in *Rstudio* (compiling is one in Rstudio, because the file needs to be saved as some kind of markdown file, right?). Is it advisable to compile (its called "knit" there) the whole document in *Rstuido*, or would I rather compile the figures separately and include them in the original LaTeX document (similar to the way I would call `tikzexternalize`?

Comment: @Max In Rstudio you can use Rmarkdown  (markdown with R chunks) or Sweave documents  (Latex plus R chunks). In both cases can be exported to a LaTeX document that  make the PDF, all with only a click.  Compile each figure alone seems to me an unnecessary complication, specially if the source data could change a posteriori. R calculations will usually take few seconds even in large documents.  Moreover, you can use the  `cache=TRUE`  option in R chunks.

Comment: @Fan thx. I like the idea of automatically updating the figures (that is why I used `pgfplot` in the first place). Writing and compiling an `.Rnw` document with RStudio is indeed easy once one gets along with R. However, I am still encountering a fatal out of memory error when RStudio calls `pfdLaTeX`:* 54000001 words of memory out of 54000000*. I guess, there is no way around generating figures separately

Comment: @max Have a look at one of my suggestions here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536656/draw-invisible-axes-with-visible-labels/536662#536662

Comment: @BambOo that is exactly what I eventually did =) (the upvote here comes from me;) ) The only difference is that `matlab2tikz` fails with too much data, so you just `print` or `export` the figure and plot axes on top of the image

Comment: I did not pay attention that you asked both questions, my bad. But I guess this is the same base problem. IMHO it is not `matlab2tikz` rather than the LaTeX compiler that fails because of memory limitations. And if it doesn't fail, you will get a somewhat useless incredibly heavy pdf which is in contradiction with the principle of vector graphics, which is to get compact yet precise drawings. I really believe this problem is not specific to TeX and friends and just stems from a misuse of vector graphics.